# Oracle | drop table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to drop certain tables in a tablespace that has common name appended to end of each table for an example:

```
TABLE1_NAME1_COMMON
TABLE2_NAME2_COMMON
TABLE3_NAME3_COMMON
```

I heard about Oracle functions but I'm not familiar much with those so I'm expecting some helping hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're completely sure what you're doing, ie, if you're sure that you don't accidentally drop a table that you don't want to drop, you can do a:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000

begin
for r in (

  select table_name 
    from user_tables 
   where table_name like '%\_COMMON' escape '\')

loop

  execute immediate 'drop table ' || r.table_name;

end loop;
exception when others then
   dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

**Edit**:

1. Changed Now selecting from  `user_tables` instead of `dba_tables` as it seems more safe to do.
2. Added `set serveroutput on` in order for `dbms_output.put_line` to be printed
3. Added `begin .. exception .. end` in order for errors to be shown.

Comment: Can I ask if this is a PL/SQL thing ? or a function ?

Comment: @PerfectGundam: if you're referring to the `execute immediate ...` construct then this is a "PL/SQL thing" that allows to call dynamic PL/SQL.

Comment: Ah thank you, I was just wondering if it can be used in a similar form for different DBMSs.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that in a procedure, but it might be better to just select those `DROP`-statements, **review them** and execute them manually:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name || ';'
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE '%\_COMMON' ESCAPE '\';
```

would return

```
DROP TABLE TABLE1_NAME1_COMMON;
DROP TABLE TABLE2_NAME2_COMMON;
DROP TABLE TABLE3_NAME3_COMMON;
```

Answer (score 0):

to identify them you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM user_tables WHERE tablespace_name='MySpace' AND table_name like '%COMMON';
```

You could then either, derive your DROP statements using a SELECT. Or you could write a PL/SQL function to loop through the "Common Tables" and DROP them using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

I would make sure you are 100% sure in the selections first however.